# With this occasion

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, phrase-usage, phrase-request

I'm attempting a direct translation from my native language to English, because I can't think of the English form at the moment. I'm trying to say "because of this day, I would like to do something..."

What is the correct formulation of this sentence?

This is part of a formal email to be sent to colleagues.

The current format that I have is "With this occasion, I would like to" but sounds wrong.

Comment: I think this question is clear enough not to be closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're very close.  The idiom is "on this occasion" (or "on this happy occasion" or "on this momentous occasion") or "on the occasion of ..."

It's quite often used in speeches or toasts for special events - such as a wedding, the dedication of a new building, etc.

So examples of this are:

> On the occasion of my father's hundredth birthday, I would like to thank ...
>
> On this happy occasion, I think it is appropriate that we look back at the hard work that ...

Occasion (MW, definition 3b)

> a time at which something happens, instance : on the occasion of his daughter's wedding